# Image generation websites

Tags: image

I'm looking for a service such as `placekitten dot com` that also includes the dimensions in the image. For example, a 200x300 kitty image would have "200x300" as 'text' overlaying the picture.

Are there any other services doing this?

Comment: i now have a new favorite placeholder website.

Answer (score 4):

http://placehold.it/ shows dimensions on a generated image, but it does not have a (cute) picture behind.

Comment: +1. I'm pretty sure placehold.it is what inspired placekitten and others.